# No keyword with name 'Input Text tag=textarea testFeedback1' found

Tags: iframe, robotframework, selenium2library

Trying to test `testarea`, `email` and `send` button inside `iframe` using robot framework

code:

```
<iframe width="700" height="600" src="" name="iFrameTitle" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0">
            <form id="innerFormID" name="innerForm" action="/xxx/xxxx/yyyy/zzzz/" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                <fieldset id="ncDetailsInner">
                    <div id="element1">
                        <label for="label1">
                        <abbr title="Required field">*</abbr></label>
                        <textarea  id="innerid" name="inneridw" rows="4" cols="50"> 
</textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div id="element2">
                            <label for="label4">Email<abbr title="Required field">*</abbr></label>
                            <input id="label5" name="labelname5" type="text" maxlength="19" value="">
                        </div>

                        <div id="element4">
                            <button type="button" id="formSubmitButton">Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form> 

</iframe>
```

Tried so far:

```
Select Frame   xpath=//iframe
Input Text tag=textarea testFeedback1
Input Text tag=input test@gmail.com
Click Element  formSubmitButton
```

Got an error:

> > No keyword with name 'Input Text tag=textarea testFeedback1' found.

Any help or pointers are appreciated to make it work properly. Thank you!

Comment: Check that you have enough spaces between "Input Text" and "tag=...". Robot Framework requires at least two spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a space character. Notice that the error message thinks you are trying to run the keyword `Input Text tag=textarea tstFeedback1`. It does *not* think the keyword is `Input Text`.

Put two or more spaces after `Input Text` and also after `tag=textarea` (and do likewise for the next line.